# Pergunta já tem resposta definida, porém não foi marcada como "aceita"

Tags: debate, resposta-aceita

Este caso pode ser específico pois faz parte de uma questão em que acompanho, mas pode voltar a ocorrer.

O usuário fez uma pergunta, esta pergunta teve algumas respostas, porém o autor da pergunta achou respondeu sua própria pergunta com uma boa solução, inclusive esta resposta teve bastante votos, porém até hoje ela não foi marcada como aceita `√`.

Devemos notificar o usuário, quem sabe via comentário, para que o mesmo marque a solução encontrada como aceita?

Observação: Neste caso a solução foi do próprio autor, mas pode acontecer de a solução para a questão ser de outro usuário, e este achar que o fato de a resposta não ter a marcação de "aceita" sua solução esta incompleta ou incorreta mesma tendo votos positivos.

[Link da questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/java-android-como-exibir-no-log-o-stacktrace)

Comment: Também pode ser o caso, como eu que respondi a minha pergunta mas não marquei nenhuma como certa porque mesmo a minha resposta não a considero como certa, nem nenhuma das outras até agora.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depende.

Se há indícios de que a pessoa ainda não domina o funcionamento do Stack Exchange, é sempre útil colocar um comentário amistoso indicando o que o usuário pode fazer. Nesse caso avisar que ele pode aceitar sua resposta pode ser uma boa.

Se ele parece conhecer o funcionamento, mas pode estar tímido em relação a tomar a atitude porque pode não ser bem visto, então pode haver um incentivo também. Isso sempre é muito subjetivo, mas é uma linha geral de como proceder.

O que não pode é ficar incomodando usuários exigindo que eles façam algo que não é obrigatório. Ficar exigindo que ele aceite uma resposta não é apropriada, principalmente se o usuário já sabe sobre a aceitação.

A questão é o conteúdo dessa notificação. Algo amistoso para ajudar o entendimento é sempre algo bom. Exigir que o outro faça o que cada um acha que ele deve fazer é ruim, é "trollagem".

Me parece que esse é o primeiro caso. Mas expus o que acho que deve ser usado em qualquer caso, baseado em discussões e postagens prévias em inglês ocorridas na rede.

Comment: Seu ponto de vista foi bastante útil, sendo assim vou dar esta indicação em um comentário ao usuário como forma de melhorar e ajudar na identificação da solução correta.

Comment: No momento certo, um comentário com link para [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/74) pode ajudar.

Comment: Entendo o ponto e concordo parcialmente, mas penso que ao aceitar a resposta a documentação fica mais legível e até mais completa. Imagine em uma pergunta que teve 10 respostas. Uma serviu para quem perguntou mas eu, enquanto pessoa com a mesma dúvida, não sei qual foi e vou ter que investigar. Não temos um meio termo pra isso?

Comment: @leonardopessoa que meio termo? O que está propondo?

Comment: Não tenho solução mas acho que é um ponto pertinente pra se discutir. O meio termo é melhor a visibilidade da solução, mesmo quando o usuário não aceita, sem ser invasivo ou forçando.