# Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas

Tags: suporte, faq, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas

- Sua pergunta foi fechada?
- Recebeu uma chuva de votos negativos?
- Recebeu um monte de comentários desagradáveis?
- O caso foi considerado tão grave que os moderadores até deletaram a sua pergunta?
- E tudo isso aconteceu em menos de meia hora?

Bem, então é para você que estamos mantendo esse guia de...

## ... como NÃO fazer perguntas no StackOverflow em Português

Veja nas respostas abaixo o que você **não** deve fazer em sua pergunta e veja quais são os tipos de perguntas que não aceitamos na nossa comunidade, que ninguém por aqui gosta e que ninguém vai querer perder tempo em responder. Dentre os casos mais comuns e recorrentes de perguntas mal elaboradas que atraem votos de fechamento, votos negativos e comentários desagradáveis rapidamente, temos:

- [Redação de má qualidade.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5811/132)
- [Não postar o seu código ou a sua mensagem de erro.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/132)
- [Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/132)
- [Postar código como imagem.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132)
- [Perguntas sobre o mercado de trabalho ou sobre cursos na área de programação ou sobre qual é a melhor linguagem de programação.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5487/132)
- [Links para o código completo, sem nem ao menos postar nenhum código na pergunta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5489/132)
- [Perguntas de âmbito legal, relacionadas a programação.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5488/132)
- [Títulos genéricos demais ou que levam a ambiguidade.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5490/132)
- [ESCREVER EM CAIXA ALTA TODA A PERGUNTA E TAMBÉM O TÍTULO, QUE CONTÉM AS INFORMAÇÕES DO PROBLEMA OU AS DIFICULDADES QUE ESTÁ ENFRENTANDO.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5505/132)
- [Postar perguntas na área de respostas.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5509/132)
- [Complementar o conteúdo da sua pergunta usando o campo de respostas.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5510/132)
- [Não se comportar com civilidade.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5808/132)
- [Não fornecer um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/132)
- [Não entender o modelo de perguntas e respostas do site.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7257/132)

Recebemos perguntas com esses problemas quase todos os dias, então não pense que você é o primeiro. A maioria delas atraem votos de fechamento, votos negativos e comentários desagradáveis rapidamente, e acabam sendo fechadas e deletadas (motivo pelo qual você não vai achar muitas delas por aí).

Se você pretende fazer uma pergunta que se assemelha aos casos listados abaixo, aqui vai um conselho: **não faça!** Por favor, não queremos que você poste isso! Ou então, repense *muuuuuuuuuuito* bem sobre o que você vai perguntar para ter certeza de que é uma pergunta bem elaborada.

Ah, e se você já fez alguma pergunta e alguém postou um comentário com um link para cá, então tenho más notícias para você: sua pergunta tem sérios problemas.

---

Para quem quiser responder essa pergunta aqui no meta, poste casos comuns e recorrentes (e não que ocorreram apenas uma vez ou duas vezes) de perguntas problemáticas. Não precisa copiar e colar uma pergunta existente (mas se quiser fazer isso, por mim tudo bem), apenas explique bem o que é que você já está de saco cheio de socar o dedo nos botões de fechar e/ou negativar e o porquê.

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Não li ainda, mas já votei :D faz tempo que eu queria fazer isso.

Comment: Parabéns pela iniciativa. Exemplificar como não perguntar é mais eficaz do que dizer como fazê-lo. Talvez um link em [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para aqui fosse útil.

Comment: @ramaral ou até mesmo uma nova hot key [dontask] ou assim.

Comment: Victor grande ideia que isto é.

Comment: Sim @JorgeB., mas mesmo que isso não venha a acontecer podemos, no decurso de uma análise na fila, fazer referência para aqui.

Comment: [Pergunta também relevante](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2537) com uma respostas que tocam no assunto!

Comment: @BrunoCosta Sim, foi revendo essa minha resposta antiga que tive a ideia de criar esse tópico no meta.

Comment: Creio que você poderia criar uns tópicos no post, com um breve resumo das respostas já postadas indo direto para elas, para assim a pessoa que vir ler ja identificar qual (acha) que se enquadra com a sua pergunta. Pois geralmente as pessoas só leem parte do conteúdo. (o que esta no inicio)

Comment: Exemplo : [Pergunta com imagem](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/14213)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Feito.

Comment: Tentei colocar os links como ancoras para evitar recarregar a página inteira, mas não tem esse recurso: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209342/how-to-link-as-an-anchor-link-to-another-answer-in-same-page

Comment: A idéia é boa, mas os textos em geral estão ficando demasiado longos e pouco objetivos. Pra faq tem que ir direto ao ponto. Não faça A, pelos motivos B e C, com consequencia D.

Comment: @Bacco concordo, é tudo informação útil, mas pra mandar o cara vir aqui e ler tudo isto não acho que ajude alguma coisa. FAQ deveria ser algo mais curto e mais específico. Esta pergunta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/101 que não era pra ser FAQ já era criticada e era tudo curtinho. Ficar *linkando* pra cá não me parece produtivo para o novato. Mesmo que *linke* para uma resposta específica para mostrar o erro específico que a pessoa cometeu, algumas estão tão longas que não vai servir pra muita coisa. Até deveria, mas não vai acontecer na maioria dos casos.

Comment: O que mais me irrita são os erros básicos de ortografia que dificultam o entendimento :@ Acho que deveria entrar na lista também.

Comment: @CalebeOliverira. Concordo, mas não consegui elaborar uma argumentação convincente nisso. No entanto, sinta-se livre para adicionar uma resposta nova.

Comment: E quanto às perguntas que são abandonadas pelo OP? Eu vejo muitas questões com respostas, muitas delas são respostas boas e que solucionam o problema, no entanto, permanecem abertas. Acho importante abordar isso. Na tag "javascript" há muitas perguntas desse tipo.

Comment: O seu questionamento é acerca de perguntas que ficam abandonadas e quem a postou nunca mais volta ou acerca de perguntas já respondidas que ficam por lá abertas para respostas adicionais mesmo que sejam anos depois de a pergunta ter sido criada?

Comment: Sobre perguntas que são feitas e que, apesar de respondidas por outros usuários, não são marcadas como respondidas pelo OP.  As perguntas devem continuar aceitando mais respostas para o problema endereçado, mas uma delas, com certeza, foi a que resolveu o problema proposto inicialmente, portanto, deveria ser marcada como resposta, tirando o post da lista de não respondidas.

Comment: Acho que você se refere então a isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/452/132 - Se for isso, então esse é, a meu ver, um problema diferente do que o que está sendo debatido aqui.

Comment: Ótima iniciativa. Este é um ótimo material, o qual todos usuários novatos deveriam ler pelo menos uma vez.

Answer (score 97):

## Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça

Copiar e colar o enunciado do seu trabalho de faculdade aqui e achar que nós o faremos para você não vai funcionar. O trabalho é seu, o estudante é você, então é você quem tem que fazer.

Lembre-se: os usuários do Stack Overflow não são seus escravos e nem são membros de alguma entidade filantrópica que produz código de graça para qualquer um que vier pedir simplesmente porque veio pedir.

Ah, e se você disser na sua pergunta que "*não sabe como fazer*", "*não tem ideia de por onde começar*" ou que "*é urgente*", sinto muito, isso só vai piorar as coisas, pois vai passar a impressão que você não tem capacidade para fazer o curso que estiver fazendo e que portanto não merece ajuda.

**POR OUTRO LADO**, se você quiser uma ajuda, dicas ou orientações, ao invés de algo no tipo "*façam o meu trabalho para mim*", então daí pode ser que você tenha mais sorte. Poste o seu código, mesmo se estiver incompleto (preferencialmente compilável, se possível) ou mesmo que possua bugs e erros e peça ajuda. Se você tentou fazer e deu um erro que você não sabe qual é a solução, esse é o lugar certo para pedir ajuda. A única coisa que não dá é esperar que alguém faça tudo.

Ah, e já houve casos de engraçadinhos que tentaram enganar membros da comunidade para tentar induzir eles a fazerem o trabalho todo. Uns apresentavam desculpas esfarrapadas ou contavam histórias surreais, outros evitavam dar muitos detalhes. Alguns mais ousados até colocavam algum código que sabiam que não tinha relação com o problema ou com a solução desejada para fingir que tentaram algo. Eles não tiveram um final feliz...

Comment: Algumas pessoas argumentam que não estão pedindo para fazer para eles, eles só querem a solução inteira pronta, mas não precisa fazer pra eles. Só um detalhes, o código não precisa ser compilável, mas passível de compilar se acertar algum problema, muitas vezes o problema é justamente que não dá para compilar. Mas precisa ter tudo para que seja possível.

Comment: Vou até favoritar essa página pra sempre que eu ver alguém postando pergunta de faculdade mandar para a pessoa.

Comment: Não entendo por que fazem faculdade, ou curso, gastando tempo e dinheiro justamente para aprender, o professor tá lá pra isso – mas pedem para outro alguém resolver os exercícios.

Comment: @epx ainda mais de graça, se ao menos pagassem poderia haver uma relevação kk

Answer (score 70):

## Postar código como imagem

Então você colocou uma imagem do seu código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Entenda os motivos lendo com atenção o texto abaixo.

Por exemplo, observe isso:

[image: código como imagem]

Agora, vamos supor que há alguém que esteja disposto a responder a pergunta. Talvez essa pessoa tenha uma sugestão de melhoria em determinada parte do código ou tem algumas ideias de como resolver o problema. Por exemplo, esse alguém que quer responder a pergunta, pode querer copiar o código e alterar algo dentro do método `defaultHeaders` para fazer algum teste ou tentar arrumar algum problema. Normalmente eis o que quem quer responder a pergunta faria:

1. Copiar o código que o autor da pergunta fez.
2. Colar o código em alguma IDE ou editor de texto.
3. Compilar o código para ver que tipo de erro aparece.
4. Começar a fazer experimentos, testes, alterar algumas coisas, quebrar a cabeça, etc.
5. Encontrar a solução.
6. Postar uma resposta.

Entretanto, se você postou o seu código como uma imagem, e não como um texto, o que acontece é que quem for responder não vai conseguir nem realizar o passo 1 acima, quanto mais realizar o passo 6. Se não der para copiar o código que você deu como texto, dificilmente alguém vai conseguir responder a pergunta de forma satisfatória. Você vai ficar sem respostas em sua pergunta!

É verdade que quem for responder a pergunta poderia redigitar todo o código da imagem. Mas também é verdade que este é um trabalho chato, tedioso, demorado e principalmente **propenso a erros**. E esse trabalhão todo poderia ser evitado se a pessoa que fez a pergunta colaborasse. Assim sendo, muitos usuários acabam pensando o seguinte:

> Para que vou perder alguns minutos do meu tempo redigitando isso tudo para fazer algo que o autor da pergunta poderia ter feito em alguns segundos? É mais fácil pedir para ele copiar e colar o código dele aqui.

Portanto, não poste código como imagem! Nunca! Jamais! Imagens devem ser usadas apenas para coisas tais como figuras, desenhos, diagramas, prints de tela, etc.

---

Se você escolheu postar como figura porque não sabe formatar o seu código como texto para aparecer adequadamente, prefira postar malformatado mesmo e pedir ajuda para formatá-lo da maneira correta.

Dica: O Stack Overflow formata como código, todas as linhas que começam por quatro espaços (essa é a forma antiga de formatação em bloco). Dessa forma (observe que cada linha começa com quatro espaços):

```
1234 - Contando os espaços

    print("Hello")
    if 1 < 2:
        print("World")
```

Além disso, você pode selecionar todo o texto do seu código e apertar o botão [image: {}] ou então apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> para que sejam colocados quatro espaços no começo de cada linha do texto selecionado.

Também há uma forma nova de formatação de código em bloco. Que consiste em colocar uma linha com ```` ``` ```` antes do código e uma linha com ```` ``` ```` após ele. Por exemplo:

````
```
print("Hello")
if 1 < 2:
    print("World")
```
````

Veja ainda mais informações [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/132).

Comment: É pelo menos o perguntador deveria facilitar quem vai responder fazer o que ele já deveria ter feito, testar o código adequadamente. Muitas vezes o código é necessário porque a solução precisa de um teste que ele não fez e muitas vezes acaba passando pela análise do código funcionando para chegar na solução.

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/Gusu5Af.png](http://i.imgur.com/Gusu5Af.png)

Comment: além disso normalmente é mais fácil postar o codigo como texto do que uma imagem.

Comment: @Gabe Esse comentário é dos mais épicos que vi por aqui no meta :D

Comment: Um adendo https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635

Answer (score 59):

## ESCREVER EM CAIXA ALTA TODA A PERGUNTA E/OU TAMBÉM O TÍTULO, QUE CONTÉM AS INFORMAÇÕES DO PROBLEMA OU AS DIFICULDADES QUE ESTÁ ENFRENTANDO.

Comment: Sinceramente, além de desagradável, isso é muito irritante...

Answer (score 58):

## Não postar o seu código ou a sua mensagem de erro

Há usuários que acham que os demais usuários do Stack Overflow têm poderes mágicos telepáticos de clarividência e são capazes de adivinhar com exatidão o que é que está acontecendo no ambiente de quem pergunta. Acreditam que esses seres StackOverflownianos dotados de superpoderes podem adivinhar qual é o código, a mensagem de erro, a configuração do sistema e todas as outras informações necessárias sem precisar ver nada sobre isso e ainda são capazes de descobrir o que há de errado nisso tudo. Dessa forma, esses usuários acreditam que não é necessário colocar essas informações no texto da pergunta pois elas podem ser obtidas por quem responde através de meios sobrenaturais e paranormais.

Segue abaixo alguns exemplos reais de perguntas desse tipo. Todas foram postadas menos de uma semana antes da qual estou redigindo esta resposta.

1.

> ### Estou precisando de ajuda no xcode8.1 viewcontrollers e seus botoes( I need help with swift3 (two viewcontrollers and their buttons))
>
> Criei uma seguunda view controller , mais na hora que eu adiciono a outlet do button da segunda viewcontroller o programa nao roda, da fatal error.(I created a safe view controller, but the time I add the outlet of the button of the second viewcontroller the program does not run, the fatal error. )Pls
>
> [xcode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) [uiviewcontroller](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiviewcontroller)

2. 

> ### JAVA: como fazer com que as atualizações de um frame para o outro sejam numa mesma tela?
>
> Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde gostaria que os valores que passo do Frame1 para o Frame2 aparecessem numa mesma tela, porém, não está dando certo, porque sempre aparece uma tela nova de acordo com as novas atualizações que faço; como resolver isso?
>
> Obrigado desde já.
>
> [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

3. 

> ### Sistema de cadastro de produtos
>
> ola pessoal estou precisando de uma ajudinha
>
> Quero fazer um sistema de cadastro de produtos como se fosse uma venda online onde o cliente visualiza a quantidade do estoque dos produtos caso ele fizer uma compra na base de dados devera subtrair pela quantidade solicitada .
>
> Ex: na base de dados tem 12 Iphone em estoque e o cliente faz compra de 3 na base de dados de subtrair e ficar somente 9.
>
> [cadastro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cadastro)

E aí, conseguiu entender exatamente o que é que eles estão pedindo sem restar nenhuma dúvida? Já percebeu em qual linha do código é que está o erro? Já tem uma ideia de como postar uma resposta? Pois é, nós também não! Então, por favor, não poste perguntas assim.

Lembre-se que ninguém aqui consegue adivinhar o que está acontecendo em seu sistema e nem vai conseguir saber se você não der informações suficientes e nem se esforçar um pouquinho na redação da sua pergunta.

Comment: E o pior é que muita gente acha que é obrigação nossa ter esses poderes.

Comment: A SE esta desenvolvendo um tecnologia de telepatia para resolver isto, ela ainda será capaz de prever o futuro e contemplar o passado, será bem baratinho, dizem que alguns usuários do SOen já tem acesso. Suas duvidas serão respondidas :)

Comment: Sem falar que muitas vezes quando você busca explicar o máximo possível para quem vai ler a pergunta, dando os detalhes, você mesmo acaba achando a solução, simplesmente por notar uma particularidade que antes não havia reparado.

Answer (score 43):

## Perguntas sobre o mercado de trabalho ou sobre cursos na área de programação ou sobre qual é a melhor linguagem de programação

Você já deve ter visto um monte de perguntas sobre códigos em Java, C, C++, PHP, C#, Javascript, Python, etc. por aqui, não é mesmo? Logo, esse deve ser um bom lugar para perguntar qual dessas é a melhor linguagem para focar os seus estudos, qual dessas vale mais a pena investir, ou qual é a melhor empresa para se trabalhar com isso, né?

### Não!

Não, perguntas sobre mercado de trabalho em linguagens de programação, sobre qual linguagem vale ou não a pena investir tempo e dinheiro ou sobre qual é o melhor curso ou faculdade a se fazer não são bem-vindas por aqui. Qual é o melhor tutorial ou qual tutorial deve ser indicado também não é uma boa pergunta. Aqui são bem vindas as perguntas de caráter mais técnico, aquelas onde você está mexendo nos ifs e whiles, ou mesmo desenhando diagramas de entidades em um papel. Isso é bem diferente de perguntar qual é a melhor empresa a se trabalhar, qual é a melhor faculdade a se cursar, qual é a melhor linguagem para se aprender ou qual é o melhor tutorial para estudar.

Não misture alhos com bugalhos!

## Mas por que não, afinal de contas?

É porque ninguém aqui pode dar uma boa resposta a uma pergunta dessa e provavelmente todas as respostas recebidas vão ser ruins. Isso é algo muito pessoal e depende muito do que você quer para você. Cada um trilha um caminho diferente. Se você perguntar isso para mil pessoas diferentes, terá mil respostas diferentes, e provavelmente todas erradas, pois a melhor pessoa que pode responder isso a você é você mesmo.

Perguntar "*qual é a melhor linguagem de programação?*" é uma coisa que cria um debate pouco produtivo, onde cada um tenta vender o seu peixe, puxando a sardinha para o seu lado e não se chega a conclusão nenhuma. O resultado é que a pergunta acaba virando mais uma conversa de boteco, e não é esse o propósito do site. Em outras palavras, é uma pergunta **opinativa** e não **objetiva**. Veja mais sobre isso em [gorila vs tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/132).

Em uma pergunta do tipo "*qual é o melhor curso?*" ou "*qual é a melhor empresa para se trabalhar?*", isso fica ainda pior, pois a conversa atrairá pessoas que virão fazer propagandas, fazer propagandas negativas, fazer spam, postar respostas com conteúdo puramente promocional e marketeiro, dar respostas que só se aplicam a determinadas cidades, etc. Essas coisas não deveriam fazer parte de uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas para problemas de programação (e não problemas de mercado).

Já outras perguntas do tipo "*é melhor trabalhar como CLT ou PJ?*" não são perguntas sobre programação afinal de contas, e sim sobre aplicação de leis trabalhistas e sobre RH, logo não faz parte do escopo deste site.

No fim das contas, para esse tipo de pergunta, a única pessoa que poderia respondê-las de forma adequada é justamente quem está perguntando. E a realidade do José não é a mesma da realidade da Maria e nem a mesma realidade do Pedro. Logo, esse tipo de coisa é algo estritamente pessoal, não tem sentido de ficar por aqui.

Comment: Pior que a pessoa acha que alguma resposta será útil, aqui ou em outro lugar.

Comment: A resposta a estas perguntas é óbvia. Voce viu um monte de linguagens e nao sabe qual usar. É simples... **escolha uma, ninguém tem o direito de decidir isso por voce**. Voce mais tarde pode dedicar o seu tempo aprender outras linguagens que voce quer. Voce verá que muitas das práticas em programacao tem equivalente em quase todas as linguagens. Um conselho comum é também nao comecar por assembly nem por linguages exotéricas... mas se for isso que voce goste... porque nao!!?

Comment: "Não, perguntas sobre mercado de trabalho (...) não são bem-vindas por aqui." Nem no chat?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Acredito que no chat não haja problema nenhum.

Answer (score 36):

## Títulos genéricos demais ou que levam a ambiguidade

Por favor, descreva um título de uma forma que seja fácil de entender o contexto.

Segue abaixo, exemplos de **como não criar** títulos, por serem genéricos demais:

- *Problema no .net*
- *PHP dá erro*
- *JavaScript não funciona*
- *Problema no XCode*
- *Me ajudem!!! URGENTE!!!!*

Imagine, por exemplo, se todos criassem títulos dessa forma.
As perguntas são em sua maioria, problemas. Portanto, todos os títulos poderiam ser sempre "*problema no XXX*", "*problema no YYY*". Enfim, tudo seria intitulado da mesma forma.

Pior ainda é colocar "*me ajudem*", "*quero ajuda*" ou "*urgente*" no título, pois uma vez que se você fez uma pergunta aqui no site, é quase certo de que você está querendo ajuda e se possível para o quanto antes. Se isso fosse algo aceito, pelo menos uns 90% das perguntas aqui do site poderia ter "*me ajudem*" ou "*urgente*" no título.

Criar títulos assim é algo desorganizado, desleixado e dificulta até para quem faz a pergunta, pois títulos ruins tendem a ser negativados e ignorados.

## Ambiguidade ou divergência com o contexto.

> **Bug no PHP MVC erro 500**
>   
> Envio um formulário e me retorna o erro 500. Esse é o log do Apache:
>
> 2016-01-01 00:00:00 bla-bla-bla mod_rewrite syntax error
>
> tags: [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [bug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug), [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc), [deu-ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deu-ruim), [erro-500](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro-500), [me-ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/me-ajuda)

Pelo título e até pela tag, quem tem interesse em PHP vai entrar para ver a pergunta e logo votará para negativar ou postará comentários diversos.

O contexto em si, não apresenta nada relacionado a MVC ou PHP e vemos claramente que é algo relacionado a erro interno com sintaxe no htaccess (provavelmente).

Abaixo, um tipo de situação comum. O título não apresenta um dado essencial e normalmente confunde o leitor, induzindo-o a responder mais focado no título do que em pequenos detalhes no corpo da pergunta.

## Pequenos detalhes fazem diferença

> **Excluir arquivos com PHP**
>
> Como excluir arquivos com PHP de forma eficiente e rápida? Eu uso
>   funções recursivas para tal tarefa com rmdir() e unlink(), mas existe
>   forma melhor para fazer? Não quero soluções por linha de comando com
>   exec().

Ao ver o título, muitos já imaginam que uma forma mais prática e eficiente é fazer a operação por linha de comando, usando recursos do próprio sistema operacional do servidor e pode não prestar muita atenção no pequeno detalhe na pergunta: "*Não quero soluções por linha de comando com exec()*".

Nesses casos, quem responde recebe negativos do próprio autor da pergunta o que induz outros a "negativarem em massa", mesmo que a resposta não seja totalmente errada.

Para reduzir esse tipo de situação, inclua, no título, dados que sejam vitais.

Exemplo de como o título poderia ser mais adequado:

*Excluir arquivos com PHP sem usar linha de comando com exec()*

De um modo geral, por favor, seja claro e específico no título para evitar confusões.

Answer (score 32):

## Links para o código completo, sem nem ao menos postar nenhum código na pergunta

Evite pedir para que leiam códigos em outro link/website. Poste os trechos de códigos relevantes no corpo da pergunta, com uma boa descrição sobre o que o código deveria fazer, como deveria retornar os resultados.

Não colocar nenhum código e deixar apenas um link é ruim por vários motivos, entre eles:

- links podem ficar fora do ar, ou até serem alterados/removidos com o tempo. Com isso, quem for ler sua pergunta não terá a informação completa, dificultando o entendimento do problema e a elaboração de respostas
- muitos acessam o site do trabalho, e geralmente as empresas usam proxies/firewalls, que podem bloquear justamente o link onde está seu código

Coloque seu código na pergunta. Se ele estiver muito grande (e talvez por isso você tenha achado que o melhor era colocar um link), tente reduzi-lo seguindo as dicas [desta página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

Exemplo do que **não** fazer:

> ## Função Retornando Objeto
>
> Bom dia pessoal,
>   Em meu código criei uma função php retornando um objeto, porem quando chamo essa função em um array de objetos no javascript para preenche-lo, ela preenche o array mas a aplicação não roda. No meu caso, estou usando a api do google maps, quando eu faço isso, o mapa não aparece,quando eu insiro os objetos manualmente no array, funciona normal...
>   OBS: Estou rodando a aplicação em uma plataforma de desenvolvimento RAD, então desconsidere sc_lookup que é uma função especifica da plataforma.
>   Segue o código:http://example.com/codigo-fonte
>
> [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: Jogar o principal código fonte em sites externos diminui o número de pessoas dispostas a responder uma vez que algumas tem problemas de restrições com proxy.

Answer (score 31):

## Perguntas de âmbito legal, relacionadas à programação

Perguntas sobre os cuidados que deve ter, em termos legais, quando publica a sua aplicação, não são atendidos aqui.

Ninguém nesta comunidade quer ser responsável por eventuais riscos/prejuízos que você tenha. Nós estamos cá para resolver problemas, não para os criar.

Em condições normais, quem responde aqui não tem a formação na área jurídica, e se tiver é mera "coincidência". Da mesma forma, quem vai votar na resposta normalmente não tem condição técnica de avaliar se aquilo é correto ou não.

Será melhor você contactar um advogado com experiência na área.

Comment: Esta aqui acontece com menor frequencia mas achei importante mencionar

Comment: Até pq seria um desserviço, pois quem vai estar respondendo e votando normalmente é da área de TI e não da área jurídica (incorporei na resposta).

Answer (score 24):

## Não fornecer um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável

Isso daqui é também abordado [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/132) e até temos um [tópico de ajuda oficial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), que copio integralmente aqui:

> ## Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável
>
> Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Esse código deve ser…
>
> …Mínimo – Use o mínimo possível de código capaz de reproduzir o problema
> …Completo – Forneça todas as partes necessárias para se reproduzir o problema
> …Verificável – Teste o código antes de postar para confirmar que ele reproduz o problema
>
> ## Mínimo
>
> Quanto maior o código, menor a chance de alguém enxergar o problema. Simplifique seu exemplo usando uma destas técnicas:
>
> 1. **Recomece do zero.** Crie um novo programa, e só inclua nele o necessário para reproduzir o problema. Isso pode ser mais rápido para grandes sistemas, quando você acredita saber a origem do problema. Também é útil se não puder postar o código em público por razões legais ou éticas.
> 2. **Dividir e conquistar.** Se o código for pequeno, mas você não tem ideia da causa do problema, comece a remover um pedaço de código por vez até que o problema suma – e então inclua essa última parte de volta.
>
> ## Mínimo *e* legível
>
> Mínimo não quer dizer necessariamente o mais conciso possível – um exemplo claro é melhor que um exemplo pequeno. Use nomes e indentação consistentes, e se necessário inclua comentários para explicar partes do código. Praticamente todos os editores de código têm um um comando de autoformatação – encontre e use! E **não use tabs** – elas podem aparecer bem no seu editor, mas no Stack Overflow podem sair bagunçadas.
>
> ## Completo
>
> Certifique-se de incluir toda a informação necessária para reproduzir o problema:
>
> Algumas pessoas vão querer testar a resposta antes de postar.
>
> - O problema às vezes não está onde você pensa, mas em outra parte do código.
> - Se o problema requer código server-side ou um arquivo de configuração XML, inclua ambos. Se um problema num site requer HTML, JavaScript e CSS, inclua os três.
>
> ## Verificável
>
> Para ajudá-lo a resolver seu problema, as pessoas primeiro precisam comprovar que ele existe:
>
> - **Elimine qualquer aspecto que não seja relevante para a pergunta.** Se a pergunta não for sobre um erro de compilação, garanta que não haja nenhum erro desse tipo. Use ferramentas como o [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) para validar linguagens interpretadas. Sempre valide o HTML ou XML.
> - **Garanta que o exemplo realmente reproduza o problema!** Se você resolveu o problema por acaso enquanto criava o exemplo mas não testou de novo, pode não perceber que o código que está postando não ajuda.
>
> Em certos casos ajuda desligar e reiniciar o sistema, ou testar o exemplo em outra máquina para confirmar que de fato esteja entregando um exemplo válido do problema.
>
> Para mais informações sobre como depurar seu programa para criar um exemplo mínimo, o [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) criou um blog post incrível sobre o assunto: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) <sup>(en)</sup>.

Agora que você já sabe o que é um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável, e porque o postar, deixa eu falar o que acontece se você não fizer isso:

- As pessoas vão ter dificuldade de entender o seu problema.
- Vai ser difícil você receber alguma resposta, e se receber, pode ser uma resposta de baixa qualidade, ou uma resposta genérica ou uma resposta que não resolverá o seu problema.
- Poderá receber votos negativos, ou pelo menos deixar de receber votos positivos.
- Sua pergunta pode ser fechada como um problema que não pode ser reproduzido, como ampla demais ou como não estando clara o suficiente.

Se alguém te solicitou para que você poste um *exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*, se esforce em fazê-lo. Quem te solicitou a fazer isso provavelmente é um usuário experiente do site e não iria pedir isso a toa.

Answer (score 22):

## Postar perguntas na área de respostas

Isso é uma péssima ideia. A única coisa que você vai conseguir fazendo isso vai ser que a sua pergunta/resposta seja deletada. A área de respostas é apenas para respostas.

Para fazer perguntas, clique no botão [image: Faça uma pergunta] que você vê na página principal do site. Essa é a **ÚNICA** forma permitida de postar-se perguntas por aqui.

Respostas só podem ser dadas a perguntas e não a outras respostas. Assim sendo, se você posta a sua pergunta como resposta na pergunta dos outros, não receberá respostas à sua "pergunta" porque ela nem mesmo foi postada como uma pergunta.

Além disso, a maioria das pessoas que poderia responder à sua pergunta **não** irá vê-la. O motivo é que as pessoas dispostas a responder costumam procurar perguntas interessantes nas áreas onde elas são listadas (como por exemplo, a de [perguntas ativas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active), [perguntas mais novas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) e [perguntas sem respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered)). Entretanto, se você postou a sua pergunta na área de respostas, ela não vai aparecer em nenhum desses lugares e não vai chamar a atenção de alguém que poderia respondê-la.

Postar perguntas no campo das respostas é considerado falta de educação, pois você estará poluindo o conteúdo da pergunta de uma outra pessoa. Além disso, se fosse permitido misturar perguntas no meio das respostas, o site rapidamente viraria uma bagunça desorganizada onde ninguém ia conseguir se entender direito. Por causa disso, é sumariamente proibido postar perguntas no campo de respostas.

O mais provável é que quem for ver a sua pergunta postada na área de respostas vai acabar sinalizando-a como "*isso não é uma resposta*". Essa sinalização serve para marcar respostas que tenham sérios problemas e ela avisa outros usuários mais experientes no uso do site a dar uma olhada nela. Outras pessoas vão visualizar a sua pergunta/resposta, mas não com a intenção de respondê-la, e sim ver porque ela tem uma sinalização que indica problemas sérios, e então você começará a receber comentários automáticos assim:

> Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.

Após algumas pessoas confirmarem que não se trata de uma resposta à pergunta feita originalmente, ela será deletada automaticamente (isso se os moderadores não fizerem isso primeiro manualmente).

De qualquer forma, a sua "pergunta" não será respondida e acabará sendo deletada. Portanto, não poste perguntas na área de respostas, poste perguntas apenas na área própria para perguntas. Se a sua nova pergunta tiver relação com a pergunta original, coloque um link na sua nova pergunta para a pergunta antiga. E obviamente, não deixe de descrever claramente qual é o problema que você tem para não recair em outros casos que estão listados nesta página.

Comment: Não sei se isto faz parte do escopo da faq.

Comment: @JorgeB. Esse daqui fiquei em dúvida inicialmente e refleti por algum tempo antes de me convencer de que é válido sim, afinal uma forma de não fazer uma pergunta é nem sequer postá-la como tal, o que é um erro grosseiro, fatal e infelizmente recorrente.

Comment: Victor mas aqui não será o caso de "manual de como não criar um resposta"? Eu também não tenho certezas, comentei apenas para fazer as pessoas pensarem nisso e para debaterem.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que se encaixaria nos dois casos. Uma forma de não se criar uma pergunta é postá-la como resposta. Uma forma de não se criar uma resposta é utilizá-la para fazer uma pergunta.

Comment: Victor mas é mesmo isso, aqui não é manual de como criar, mas sim como fazer. Imagina que eu faço uma pergunta do melhor que há e a coloco no campo de respostas. Não se encaixa em "como perguntar", ou encaixa?

Comment: @JorgeB. Você pode usar tanto "criar" quanto "fazer" como verbo neste caso, que na minha opinião, o resultado será o mesmo. Quanto ao fato de se encaixar ou não, mesmo que a pergunta perfeita tenha sido postada no campo de respostas, ainda assim ela tem uma falha gravíssima: ter sido postada no lugar errado.

Comment: Victor não é uma questão de semântica. O que eu quero dizer é que é diferente criar/fazer uma pergunta de baixa qualidade, outra coisa é metê-la no sitio errado.

Answer (score 21):

## Complementar o conteúdo da sua pergunta usando o campo de respostas

Pergunta é pergunta e resposta é resposta. Assim sendo, não poste em uma resposta algo que seja apenas uma parte da pergunta.

Se você recebeu comentários em sua pergunta pedindo por esclarecimentos, você deve **editar** a sua pergunta acrescentando os detalhes necessários. Postar uma resposta só deixará a sua pergunta bagunçada ao deixar metade do texto no cabeçalho da pergunta e a outra metade solta em uma das respostas.

Além disso, na [página de listagem de perguntas ativas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active), a sua pergunta irá aparecer como já tendo uma resposta (tal como na figura abaixo), pois o sistema não tem como saber que a "resposta" dada na verdade era para ser parte da pergunta. Há usuários que se sentem mais motivados a [responder perguntas que ainda não tenham respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered), e portanto, eles podem acabar nem querendo ver a sua pergunta.

[image: 1 resposta]

Portanto, lembre-se sempre que a ferramenta de edição é serventia da casa e ela está a sua disposição para ser usada. **Faça um bom proveito dela**, não se acanhe e não tenha medo de editar a sua pergunta para prestar mais esclarecimentos ou para melhorá-la de alguma outra forma. Diferente de outros sites, que ou não tem o recurso de editar ou o tem apenas para os casos mais graves, o StackOverflow em português incentiva que você use a ferramenta de edição com frequência sempre que necessário, mesmo que seja para corrigir um errinho de português. Aqui, o uso da ferramenta de edição é sempre algo a ser incentivado, apreciado e valorizado.

Portanto, não tenha medo de editar a sua pergunta para complementá-la. Não há motivo para postar uma resposta para complementar a pergunta.

Comment: Não sei se isto faz parte do escopo da faq.

Answer (score 20):

## Não se comportar com civilidade

Uma das bases do funcionamento da nossa comunidade é o bom comportamento dos usuários e o relacionamento saudável entre esses. Portanto são qualidades que valorizamos:

> Respeito, consideração, civilidade, urbanidade, equilíbrio, equidade, neutralidade, imparcialidade, sensatez, mansidão, serenidade, pacificidade, impessoalidade, urbanidade, cordialidade, amizade, prudência, humildade, calma, tranquilidade, postura diplomática, verdade, sinceridade, honestidade, etc.

E portanto, coisas que não valorizamos são:

> Comportamento rude e/ou grosseiro, prepotência, soberba, ataques pessoais, retaliações, xingamentos, ofensas, insultos, ameaças, agressividade, preconceitos de qualquer tipo (incluindo, mas não limitado a, xenofobia, racismo, sexismo), arrogância, uso de linguagem chula e vulgar, calúnias, injúrias, difamações, acusações, "carteiradas", falsidade ideológica, mentiras, plágio, desonestidade, comportamento ciumento, comportamento vingativo, perseguição, críticas não-construtivas, zombaria, bullying e outras formas de desrespeito e comportamento indesejável.

Isso é algo que deveria ser óbvio a todos, mas de vez em quando temos alguns casos onde não é isso que acontece. Se você não se comportar de forma adequada, mesmo se a sua pergunta for legítima, ninguém vai querer responder ela e a única coisa que você vai conseguir é que outros usuários te apontem onde está a porta da rua. Se você insistir, é por essa porta que você acabará sendo colocado para fora pelos moderadores.

Não importa quem você é, você não é superior aos outros usuários e os outros usuários não têm obrigação nenhuma com você. Lembre-se que ao fazer uma pergunta, você está pedindo um favor aos demais usuários de respondê-la para te ajudar, então aja sempre com humildade, serenidade e respeito.

Se você não estiver agindo de forma civilizada, pode ter certeza que outros usuários tentarão te orientar. Desobedecer, ignorar ou zombar dessas orientações é uma péssima ideia. Se fazer de vítima achando que outros usuários estão agindo em conluio contra você com a intenção de te prejudicar ou te destruir ou que existe alguma conspiração maluca por aqui, só deixará as coisas ainda piores para você.

Se você for atacado por algum usuário que não esteja agindo com civilidade, não baixe o nível e mantenha a compostura, sinalize para a moderação e continue usufruindo do site tranquilamente.

Obviamente, isso tudo não significa que você é obrigado a concordar com tudo ou que você é obrigado a abaixar a cabeça sempre. Isso é algo bem diferente do que agir com civilidade. Caso receba uma crítica construtiva da qual discorde, não responda com algo do tipo "*você é um idiota que não sabe de nada, volte ao jardim de infância*", prefira responder com "*discordo de você no que concerne ao ponto X, uma vez que usar Y não é a melhor prática e acredito que esteja equivocado na sua abordagem a Z*". Note que no debate saudável, a boa argumentação mantém o foco na lógica, nos detalhes técnicos e no conteúdo daquilo que foi postado. A postura a ser adotada pode ser neutra, fria e sem emoção ou pode ser acolhedora e conciliadora, mas nunca pode ser agressiva ou desdenhosa e nunca deve partir para ataques pessoais ou insultos.

Por fim, se você não é capaz de se comportar de forma civilizada por aqui, então você não é bem-vindo nesta comunidade e vamos pedir para que você se retire dela para que não seja retirado forçosamente.

Answer (score 20):

## Redação de má qualidade

Para redigir uma pergunta de boa qualidade, recomendamos que você tenha em mente que:

- É recomendável atentar-se ao bom uso da língua portuguesa. Escreva de forma culta. Observe o correto uso de acentuação, pontuação, gramática, ortografia, concordância verbal e nominal, uso de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas e todos os demais conceitos chatos das suas aulas de língua portuguesa.
- Pense também na formatação do seu texto, ou seja, preze pela adequada formatação de ênfases, códigos, títulos, negritos, itálicos, imagens, links, listas, entre outros. Mais detalhes sobre como formatar o seu texto podem ser encontrados [nessa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1297/132).
- Se esforce também na organização da sua pergunta. Evite escrever frases ou parágrafos demasiadamente longos, pois estes tendem a ser difíceis de se ler e de se entender. Use títulos e subtítulos quando pertinente.
- Preze pela coerência, coesão, completude e sequência lógica de ideias do seu texto.
- Perguntas que tenham um texto que começa no meio e termina na metade têm uma maior tendência de não serem entendidas pelos demais usuários e acabarem recebendo respostas ruins ou de serem fechadas como não estando claras o suficiente.
- Textos que deixam de fora informações importantes para a resolução do problema ou que contêm lacunas lógicas para o seu entendimento, também podem acabar mal.
- Assim como não se deve pecar pela falta, também não peque pelo excesso, pois textos que sejam recheados de informações desnecessárias ou de pouca relevância (ou seja, "encheção de linguiça") podem acabar por confundir ou cansar mentalmente os leitores que poderiam de outra forma, te fornecer uma boa resposta à sua pergunta.
- Textos que dão um monte de voltas e balançam para um lado e para o outro ao invés de seguirem uma sequência lógica bem definida, também são confusos e difíceis de se entender. Assim sendo, é muito importante zelar pela boa organização e estrutura do seu texto e pela qualidade de seu conteúdo.

### Revisando o texto

Não se esqueça sempre de ler, reler e revisar o seu texto antes de postar, para se certificar que não há nenhum problema. Tente ler a pergunta sob a ótica de um usuário disposto a respondê-la e que não conhece o seu problema.

Lembre-se que abaixo da caixa de edição, será renderizado o texto que você está postando, o que é muito importante para assegurar-se que a formatação é a adequada (mas não apenas isso). Portanto, veja nesse texto renderizado, se o que você está postando é de fato aquilo que você realmente queria postar.

Vários navegadores possuem corretores gramaticais de texto embutidos (configure-o para a língua portuguesa), de forma que na caixa de edição, irá ficar em sublinhado vermelho ondulado aquilo que o navegador acredita ser palavras escritas incorretamente (ignore apenas em caso de códigos ou termos técnicos que você tenha certeza que estão certos). Entretanto, mesmo se o navegador não sublinhar nada em vermelho, isso não garante que o seu texto esteja bom, e portanto revisões manuais sempre são importantes.

Caso você já tenha postado a pergunta e veja nela algum erro, edite-a prontamente.

Textos que contenham problemas podem vir a ser editados pelos demais usuários a fim de corrigi-los (por favor, não tente oferecer resistência a isso). Se os problemas forem pequenos e fáceis de se arrumar, dificilmente alguma coisa ruim vai acontecer, mas no caso de problemas maiores, é bem possível que por não entenderem exatamente o que você está pedindo, essas pessoas que estarão editando o seu texto para tentar te ajudar acabem confundindo ou bagunçando alguma coisa importante. Assim sendo, se esforce em ter um bom texto pronto logo de início quando a sua pergunta for postada, para minimizar a necessidade de que você ou outros usuários precisem corrigi-la depois.

É verdade que postar o texto inicial em seu mais alto grau de primor e perfeição é quase impossível e edições subsequentes à pergunta quase sempre se fazem necessárias. Entretanto, se o autor da pergunta se esforçou bastante em ter um bom texto inicial, mesmo que alguns pequenos erros tenham passados despercebidos e tenham que ser corrigidos depois, o resultado é que muitas respostas ruins, votos negativos, votos de fechamento e comentários de leitores que não entenderam o problema terão sido evitados, ao passo que votos positivos e boas respostas tenderão a ser obtidos.

Answer (score 14):

## Não entender o modelo de perguntas e respostas do site

Aqui vai uma lista de algumas coisas que o Stack Overflow não é e nem nunca vai ser:

- Fórum
- Chat
- WhatsApp
- Telegram
- Facebook
- Instagram
- Slack
- GitHub
- Deploy
- Service desk
- Boteco

Embora possa parecer um tanto óbvio que o Stack Overflow não é nada parecido com qualquer coisa assim, todos os dias recebemos diversas "perguntas" que nem de fato perguntam qualquer coisa concreta ou específica, tendo um formato mais parecido com o início de uma conversa de chat. Vejamos alguns casos reais:

> #### Jogo de perguntas aleatórias em c
>
> Preciso criar um jogo em C de perguntas e respostas, porém tenho que usar a função **rand**, para que a pergunta seja aletoria e não se repita. E caso o jogador acerte a questão o programa devera gerar outro número e exibir a próxima pergunta.
>
> [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

> #### Preciso criar um select que aparece varias opções! e cada uma carregue um arquivo JSON na página! Podem me ajudar?
>
> Preciso criar um select que aparece varias opções! e cada uma carregue um arquivo JSON na página! Podem me ajudar?
>
> [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) [json](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)

> #### Como abrir imagem para utilizar em CUDA?
>
> Estou fazendo um programa para ler uma imagem e trocar a cor utilizando GPU.
>
> [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [cuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda)

Observe que não é possível responder nenhuma dessas perguntas sem que houvesse uma longa conversa com os respectivos autores. Inclusive, os autores dessas perguntas provavelmente estavam esperando que houvesse esta conversa.

Entretanto, o modelo do Stack Overflow é avesso a longas conversas. O ideal é que você poste na pergunta tudo aquilo que seria necessário para que quem for responder, possa elaborar uma resposta **sem que seja necessário pedir-se esclarecimentos ou detalhes adicionais**. Da mesma forma, as respostas deveriam ser postadas completas sem que detalhes ou esclarecimentos adicionais se fizessem necessários.

É verdade que os comentários por aqui são usados para postar críticas, sugestões, elogios e para pedir esclarecimentos. Entretanto, uma coisa é quando você tem uma pergunta onde dois ou três comentários adicionais são necessários para esclarecer todos os detalhes, o que está tudo bem. Outra coisa bem diferente é quando você espera que haja trocentos comentários ou respostas diferentes para conversar e debater o assunto levantado na pergunta. Nesse último caso, a sua pergunta tem sérios problemas de formulação e acabará sendo fechada e provavelmente também negativada e após algum tempo, deletada.

Tenha sempre em mente que isso daqui não é fórum, não chat e não é Facebook. Postar uma pergunta esperando que um monte de comentários venham a se seguir não vai funcionar.

Comment: Colocaria ainda: Github ou Deploy