# Como proceder se notar possíveis comportamentos prejudiciais na fila de análise?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Não estou dizendo que a pessoa está fazendo de propósito e nem o contrário, ou se está no automático (caça medalhas), mas notei um usuário que na fila de análise para fechamento marcou várias como *"Deixar aberto"*, fui conferir as postagens, somente *~2* eu concordei (isto é um exemplo, podem ter problemas assim nas outras filas), não vou afirmar que a atitude é errada, pois pode ser interpretação minha.

O que desejo saber é como informar ao usuário que ele pode ***talvez*** estar usando a ferramenta *fila de análise* de maneira errada?

Qual seria o melhor caminho?

- Flag/Sinalizar em uma das perguntas/respostas e informar ao moderador para analisar
- Usar o formulário de contato: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact
- Abrir uma pergunta no META para o assunto específico
- Falar diretamente com o usuário por meio de comentário ou chat

Comment: Acho que sinalizar para moderação sempre é uma ótima opção nesses casos, dependendo de quem seja o usuario, até seja interessante chamá-lo no chat, mas é complicado saber a reação dele diante do que você vai dizer.

Comment: Comentei no chat com alguns sobre as perguntas que deixei aberta, primeiro deixo um comentário falando para melhorar, caso não seja editada, volto nas que ainda não foram fechadas e voto para fechar. Acho que o grande "problema" está na análise das primeiras publicações, pois na maioria das vezes as perguntas que chegam na fila para fechar são de novos usuários e eu acho que nós devemos ser mais tolerantes com novos usuários (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2037/51124). Pra mim, quem analisa a primeira publicação deve orientar os novatos a fazerem boas perguntas.

Comment: Eu sei que fechamento não é punição, só acho que antes de fechar a pergunta deve falar pro usuário melhorar, se ele não faz isso aí sim fecha que ele será "obrigado" a melhorar.

Comment: @Taisbevalle Entendo, só que realmente o problema não é para quem pergunta e sim para quem responde. De qualquer forma você pode discordar de fechar de imediato, mas você não deveria discordar do motivo, na fila de analise quando vc marca algo como "deixar aberta" você esta dizendo que o motivo do fechamento esta incorreto, entende?

Comment: Entendo e concordo em partes, reli os posts aqui no meta mesmo sobre fechamento e estou sendo mais rigorosa nas análises para fechamento de perguntas. Mas ainda acho que o problema seja na análise de primeira publicação, ela não está sendo feita de forma a auxiliar os novatos.

Comment: @Taisbevalle nestes casos se discorda do [meta-tag:comportamento] o melhor seria abrir uma pergunta de [meta-tag:debate] no Meta e discutir o problema e conscientizar a comunidade e não usar a ferramenta de modo a causar conflitos de funcionamento/entendimento.

Comment: Abrir um debate sobre a análise da primeira publicação?

Comment: @Taisbevalle não, sobre o comportamento da comunidade, por exemplo "Porque é ruim fechar a primeira publicação de um novo usuário!" (note que é uma afirmação) e apresentar seus argumentos ;)

Comment: Ah tá, mas já tem http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2035/51124 e eu concordo com a resposta do utluiz

Comment: Pessoal, volta e meia surgem esses debates sobre moderação por aqui; mas acho que essa é parte natural de como o sistema funciona. Explico: Enquanto existe um "consenso" sobre perguntas que devem ser fechadas **hoje** (o consenso muda bastante, quem está aqui desde o começo sabe bem disso), esse consenso é obtido pela média. Alguns usuários são mais lenientes, outros são mais estritos, na média temos a vontade da comunidade. Os moderadores estão de olho em comportamentos abusivos (no automático), porém divergências são esperadas. Pessoas usam as ferramentas de moderação de maneiras diferentes.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly estamos conscientes deste tipo de situação, mas o problema que acredito que o pessoal não entendeu é outro, o caso é especificamente como agir na *fila de analise*, independentemente de achar correto ou não fechar prematuramente, a questão é que as perguntas tinha sim problemas e o ato de marcar como "deixar aberta" foi por considerar que fechamentos são ruins acaso seja a primeira pergunta do usuário. O problema é que se você não concorda com o fechamento porque ele esta errôneo por parte de outros colaboradores é uma coisa, agora se o motivo esta correto...

Comment: ... e mesmo assim você marca para deixar aberto porque acredita ser prematuro é o mesmo que quebrar a lógica da ferramenta em uma pergunta especifica (na verdade isto vale para qualquer uma das filas de analise). Então é assim, "eu" concordo que o motivo de fechamento esta correto, mas marco para "deixar aberta" porque acho que é muito cedo, ainda sim será como dizer: *meus colegas estão enganados, este motivo de fechamento é o errado*. Se não concorda com fechamento prematuro o melhor é não votar para fechar e orientar o AP de modo receptivo e não usar a ferramenta "Fila" de modo incorreto.

Comment: Eu entendo Guilherme, mas isso é um problema na média? As pessoas estão dando significadow diferente à opção "deixar aberto"  (eu pessoalmente uso bastante essa opcão, diria que é o meu voto mais comum), elas usam as ferramentas de moderação de maneira diferente. Na média porém, se a pergunta for ruim mesmo ela vai ser fechada mais cedo ou mais tarde... Minha opinião é que não adianta tentar padronizar procedimentos individuais se o funcionamento da ferramenta é estatístico. Isso requer um esforço enorme para obter um valor mínimo.

Comment: Meu ponto é, se uma pergunta tem 4 votos para fechar, não sei se vai fazer tanta diferença assim escolher "deixar aberta" vs "pular", ainda mais no caso que o moderador se dispõe a voltar e mudar o voto se a pergunta não for melhorada. Acho que estamos procurando cabelo em ovo (tentar controlar esse tipo de regra não é algo eficiente). E para problemas maiores temos o Chat e moderadores de olho.

Comment: Continuo discordando de ti. Na média o comportamento dela vai ter um efeito mínimo sobre o todo (já temos volume o suficiente para isso). Tentar impor a mesma interpretação - não óbvia - para cada opção de ferramenta é um trabalho cansativo. Prefiro tratar "deixar aberta" por "deixar aberta" (Isso é, uma afirmação de que a pergunta não deva ser fechada, mesmo que o motivo seja: "Ainda dá tempo do OP arrumar"). Olho o esforço que estamos colocando em "deixa aberta agora" vs "deixa aberta pois não é ruim"... Acho um esforço enorme desnecessário, mas posso estar errado.

Comment: Não, meu critério aqui está mais próximo do seu, eu votaria para fechar e deixaria um comentário (ou apenas deixaria um comentário). Mas meu ponto é que não vale a pena tentar impor isso como certo; as vezes o comportanto mais leniente de um moderador ajuda (as vezes, pelo contrário, o comentário vai fazer com que a pergunta seja fechada mais rápido mesmo com o voto para deixar a pergunta aberta). Se a coisa começar a gerar ruído (pouco provável, eu particularmente não dou a mínima para como os outros votaram na hora de decidir) os mods vem com a marreta de ouro.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly concordo com você no início (sobre os critérios voláteis), mas o Guilherme me parece correto nesse ponto específico. Se alguém vota para deixar aberto, sai da fila de análise e a chance de fechar fica bem reduzida. Se o voto de fechamento foi dado pensando em ser transitório, a pessoa errou, o voto tem peso definitivo e até decisivo para o que vai acontecer. Para fechar precisa de 5 votos, para tirar da fila de análise precisa bem menos. Se há um erro aí, prejudica bastante.

Comment: O "Pular" parece mais adequado se quer só dar um tempo, afinal pode voltar lá depois e tomar uma decisão final. Não estou entrando no mérito do resto da questão. Note que eu não posso obrigar ninguém seguir um critério, só posso dizer o que eu acho adequado. Se a pergunta está ruim, pode fechá-la. E depois pode reabri-la. Claro que cada caso é um caso. Eu não tomo a mesma decisão sempre. Eu tento perceber o que está acontecendo ali. Eu levo em consideração o usuário quando vou fechar, porque sei que alguns usuários vão arrumar se estiver com problema. Outros eu não sei.

Comment: Melhorou bastante :). Eu também tomaria cuidado com plurais mais acertivos ("conhecemos", etc). Isso gera um sentimento de pertença e de uma massa homogênea de moderação - o que não é verdade ao meu ver. De resto, acho que para casos extremos vale a resposta do gato. Principalmente uma conversa com uns dois mods para ver se três pessoas chegam à mesma conclusão sobre o mal uso e concordam em agir (incluindo o @bigown aqui em cima, o Math, Utluiz, Bacco, etc).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly talvez gere tal sentimento, e talvez seja isso mesmo uma "massa", mas não de quem dita o que é melhor sim uma "massa" que conhece os problemas e tem maior experiencia e domínio dos problemas, e mesmo assim existe discordância, de qualquer forma apaguei o comentário. Obrigado e até mais!

Answer (score 7):

## Fechando as perguntas

Grande parte das questões que foram marcadas como **deixar aberta** estão com graves problemas e eu já comecei a votar para fecha-las, e elas realmente devem ser fechadas até que o AP edite a pergunta e a deixe de acordo com as regras definidas na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Há também o [manual](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) que ilustra os principais tipos de perguntas que NÃO devem ser feitas, ele pode ser consultado para quem for fazer perguntas e também para quem for votar para fechar. Além disso é importante para quem esta começando a atuar na moderação do site ler os tópicos da central de ajuda, da mesma forma consultar as respostas e perguntas aqui no meta da [tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/raz%C3%B5es-fechamento/info) [razões-fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raz%c3%b5es-fechamento) isso irá ajudar na hora de tomar alguma decisão para votar.

Vote para fechar as perguntas que estão relacionadas as tecnologias e linguagens que você domina, quando tiver dúvida de como votar, pode pedir auxilio no chat ou faça uma pergunta aqui no meta.

## Como eu procederia a respeito de comportamentos erroneos na fila de análise

A primeira coisa que eu faria seria trazer o problema aqui no meta para que a comunidade buscasse o melhor caminho para soluciona-lo, assim como orientar os usuários em relação aos seus erros.

A segunda coisa, eu entraria em contato com alguém da moderação, pedindo alguma orientação de como proceder.

## Considerações finais

O voto para fechar não é uma ferramenta usada para punir usuários que não sabem como perguntar, pelo contrário, ele é uma ferramenta utilizada para manter a qualidade do conteúdo no estilo Q&A.

Aqui **somos todos moderadores** então vamos dar o melhor de nós para manter a qualidade do site, e lembresse desta frase:

> Grandes poderes trazem grandes responsabilidades!
>
> Tio Ben

Comment: Então sobre os motivos de fechar ou não até acho valido discutir, eu mesmo formulei uma resposta sobre o assunto http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635, mas realmente a situação do problema que gostaria de debater é como relatar ou qual o melhor caminho para relatar. A ideia de trazer para o META parece a melhor mesmo.