# Deixar links de orientação afasta novos usuários?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Ao me deparar com [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204635/28595), ao perceber que era um usuário novo, resolvi deixar um comentário para um post do [faq](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), relativo a postar imagens de código ao invés de em forma de texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O link apenas direciona para [esta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595) de um post aqui do meta, com o resumo de diversas orientações a usuários que ainda estão aprendendo a postar no site, praticamente um resumo intuitivo da Central de ajuda.

[No chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37397102#37397102), fui questionado de que este tipo de comentário deixa novos usuários com raiva e os afastam do site, mas eu sinceramente não vejo como uma orientação benéfica a pessoa aprender a participar melhor do site pode ter um resultado tão negativo.

Já tive experiencias parecidas no SOen, mesmo não sendo tão novato assim na rede, onde fui tratado com certa rispidez, onde um usuário avaliou minha dúvida como ruim, mesmo eu tendo explicado todo o ponto da dúvida, e ao invés de me orientar onde a pergunta estava com problemas, simplesmente achou-se no direito de me "atacar". Acho válido esse tipo de post com links de orientação, quando a pessoa as vezes quer evitar um conflito usando palavras próprias, de forma a parecer rude ao outro que irá ler.

Se o usuário irá ler ou não é outro ponto diferente, mas não consegui enxergar de que forma alguém se sentiria irritado com algo feito com a intenção de ajudar.

Gostaria da opinião de vocês, postar links para o faq, central de ajuda ou outros posts orientativos do meta realmente causam esse efeito?

Comment: Meio que infelizmente é assim, tudo que indica para o usuário novo a ler, estudar e entender como funciona a comunidade, vai acabar tendo o efeito contrario, tem gente que simplesmente tem preguiça de começar lendo tutoriais, e só busca o tutorial depois de uma certa experiencia, e quando quer algo mais minucioso.

Comment: Me botando no lugar do novato: "eu posto uma pergunta em uma rede de programadores, ai vem o pessoal com links em vez de me darem a solução do meu problema? Oras bolas eu queria uma resposta pra minha duvida, não um link pra eu **supostamente** aprender a usar a ferramenta".

Comment: Detalhe, li o contexto da sua duvida no chat agora, e sou a favor de comentários com links ensinando novatos a usarem a ferramenta rs, porem eu tenho consciência que a maioria nem vai ler, e apos casos como o [spencer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22522/spencer-ekroth), já to meio calejado de que, nem sempre comentários amigáveis irão realmente ajudar

Comment: @MarceloBoni eu já penso diferente. Antes de comentar penso: se fosse pra mim seria útil? E quase sempre a resposta é sim. Mesmo se não for,  não é culpa nossa se a outra pessoa entendeu a "mensagem" como crítica. Infelizmente por mais que nos esforcemos, estamos sempre sujeitos a sermos interpretados de forma equivocada. :/

Comment: Não posso afirmar pelo usuário, mas pensei duas coisas: Uma é que o cara precisa acessar o link pra entender o que se espera dele e outra é que o título pode soar negativo. Mais uma vez, não posso afirmar pelo usuário mas, talvez, e digo apenas talvez, se fosse "Por favor insira o código em formato texto veja -> Manual de *como* fazer perguntas", o resultado fosse mais positivo.

Answer (score 9):

> (...) este tipo de comentário deixa novos usuários com raiva e os afastam do site(...)

Sou usuário do Stack Exchange há anos e tenho uma opinião forte formada sobre isso. O que eu vou falar aqui pode soar como uma generalização ou estereotipagem. Os usuários novatos que se sentem ofendidos com:

- links sobre os padrões do site;
- comentários informando sobre a melhor forma de perguntar e responder;
- alterações em seus posts para adequá-los aos nossos padrões.

... são *quase* sempre pessoas que não vão mudar sua forma de agir só porque é inadequada. É que nem gente que só manda áudio em aplicativo de mensagem.

Eu divido as pessoas que postam no Stack Exchange em três grupos:

- ex-lurkers: pessoas que sondam o site muito tempo antes de se tornarem ativas. Elas aprendem os padrões do site antes de usá-lo, e em geral já começam por aqui com bons posts;
- veteranos endurecidos: gente que aprendeu a usar o site através da experiência. Cometeram erros, aceitaram as críticas, foram corrigidos e hoje são usuários exemplares. Talvez sejam a maioria.
- *code monkeys*: o termo *code monkey* descreve um programador com pouca capacidade de pensamento crítico, que frequentemente adere à filosofia **go horse** de desenvolvimento - ou seja, as soluções são para o aqui e o agora, sem maiores preocupações como causas ou consequências. Em geral postam uma única pergunta mal formatada, por vezes indicando que precisam da solução com urgência. Ao ser criticado, o *code monkey* realiza um *rage quit* e vai buscar a solução em sites mais alinhados com a sua forma de pensar, como o Yahoo! Respostas.

No fim do dia, é bem verdade que a nossa dureza não afasta apenas maus usuários. É possível que a gente possa perder o Alan Turing da nossa geração por sermos ríspidos demais. Mas é essa rispidez que mantém os *code monkeys* afastados, então eu acredito que temos mais a ganhar do que a perder ao exigir que novos usuários leiam o manual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente. No geral você acha que há uma certa rispidez, ou pelo menos algumas pessoas podem considerar assim, ou há claramente uma rispidez **demais**. stou querendo dar uma resposta, mas ela vai longe e não está sobrando tempo de fazer legal.

Comment: É, mas rispidez é questão de opinião. O que muita gente por aqui considera raiz eu considero nutella. Quem quer ver rispidez de verdade devia mandar *pull request* pro Linus Torvalds pra ver o que é ser amaldiçoado até a sétima geração.

Comment: Eu vi :D Mas eu não ligo, eu aceito o ignorante, suporto o arrogante, só não suporto quando junta os dois :)

Comment: Eu ainda não vi nenhuma rispidez num simples comentário com um link.