# Recortar comentários e colar em uma nova pergunta é uma boa conduta?

Tags: debate

## Cenário Hipotético

Ao fazer uma pergunta um usuário recebeu vários comentários e decide respondê-los no contexto de outra pergunta.

## Motivação

A dúvida surgiu porque percebi que o SO não possui um sistema de resposta aninhado, como o do facebook por exemplo que você pode responder diretamente a um comentário, e essa resposta ficar aninhada abaixo do comentário principal.

Imagino que um usuário que entre em uma pergunta desse tipo, não se sinta motivado a ler aquilo tudo, já que se tivesse rendido algo, teria virado uma resposta e não uma discussão.

Apesar de reconhecer que pode acontecer de sair uma boa resposta de uma vasta lista de comentários, mas paro e penso que se realmente fosse uma boa resposta não estaria de fato ali (nos comentários).

## Dúvida geral

Usar o contexto do recurso "faça uma pergunta" e usá-lo para responder comentários de outras perguntas é uma boa prática?

## Dúvidas específicas

> ### Caso 1
>
> > Recortar comentários de uma "pergunta 1" e colar esses comentários na "pergunta 2" (procurando respondê-los) é considerado uma boa conduta?
>
> #### Caso 2
>
> > Recortar comentários da "pergunta 1" e fazer edições da mesma "pergunta 1" com esses comentários e respondendo eles é uma boa conduta?

## Observações

Para deixa menos subjetivo, considere que a pergunta hipotética recebeu muitos comentários(tipo uns 10) e muito grandes(mais de 300 caracteres).

Comment: Acabei por não perceber a sua dúvida.

Comment: Jonathas o que você quer saber é se pode fazer como faz no facebook, criar uma nova publicação (pergunta) com o seu comentário para que posso haver um discussão só relativamente ao seu comentário?

Comment: Fazer uso do recurso "publicação" (pergunta) para responder comentários de terceiros no corpo da publicação e não no corpo do comentário, exatamente pra não ficar aquela "sopa" de letrinhas sem saber quem ta se dirigindo a quem (quando não usa a marcação "@alguem")

Comment: Jonathas agora que percebi, não podes fazer isso não. O melhor que podes fazer é usar a marcação "@alguem" que cria notificação.

Answer (score 5):

Perguntar não ofende. E o meta é o lugar certo para se tirar dúvidas sobre como utilizar o SO.

Porém, como em qualquer outra comunidade voltada para diletantes, entusiastas e profissionais de TI, existe um compromisso implícito, aquela regra não escrita assumida por cada usuário.

[image: Leia o manual]

Especificamente, este: [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), do qual eu cito, com ênfase minha:

> Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada e possivelmente removida, evite fazer perguntas subjetivas onde...
>   * **não haja um problema real para resolver: “Tenho curiosidade de saber se outras pessoas se sentem como eu.”**
>   * você faça uma pergunta **hipotética e aberta:** “E se acontecer ______?”

Local para se responder comentário é nos comentários. Se achar que há comentários demais em uma publicação e quiser continuar a conversa, vá para o chat.

Comment: Alias se os comentários se alongarem muito o próprio sistema do site aconselha a ir para um chat especifico da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Se for pra responder assim em abstrato, eu diria que não, não é uma boa ideia colar um comentário no campo de pergunta. Se algo foi postado como comentário, dificilmente terá o formato adequado para uma pergunta – formato que a [ajuda oficial](/dont-ask) descreve em linhas gerais e a comunidade [exemplifica](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483) aqui no meta.

Isso não quer dizer que o conteúdo de um comentário (ou vários) não seja material fértil para perguntas. Muito pelo contrário. Mas quem pergunta precisa costurar esses comentários num discurso próprio, podendo ou não citar os tais comentários diretamente. Esse discurso (como idealmente o de todas as perguntas do site) serve para contextualizar a dúvida, definir os pressupostos e os limites do que está sendo perguntado.

Em resumo, transformar diretamente (copy/paste) o texto de um comentário em pergunta não é uma boa. Mas pegar o gancho de uma dúvida que apareceu nos comentários e fazer uma pergunta sobre isso não tem problema nenhum, desde que dentro do escopo e demais limites do site.

Comment: Ah com a tua resposta é que consegui agora entender a pergunta. Fui ler de novo e acho que não é bem isto que ele pergunta.

Comment: @jorgeb entao me explica que eu é que não entendi!

Comment: bfavaretto vê o comentário dele.