# Perdi pontuação como faço para melhorar?

Tags: suporte, pontos

Como posso melhorar minhas perguntas quando perco meus pontos e não recebo nenhum alerta nem dica, apenas perco pontuação?, isto é correto?

Pois fiz uma pergunta recentemente e depois de pouco tempo apareceu que eu tinha perdido 2 pontos, mas a pessoa que retirou eles não explicou o motivo e fiquei chateado com isso

Comment: Não sei exatamente a qual postagem se refere, mas se for sobre perguntas, isso pode ajudar bastante: [Guia de Sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](/q/8089/70) - Sobre "ficar chateado", não tem necessidade disso, um negativo não significa que as pessoas não gostam de você, simplesmente é um indicativo que algo precisa ser melhorado (ou seja, é bom pra você, no fim das contas, ja é um indicativo de que a postagem tem algo problemático). Para resolver, é só ir seguindo a documentação e as dicas da comunidade (e tomar como referência outras postagens de assuntos que gosta com positivos).

Comment: Obrigado, e só mais uma pergunta, quando você recebe um negativo perde pontos?

Comment: Veja na central de ajuda todos os casos em que alguém ganha ou perde pontos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: PS: aqui no meta você não perde pontos por receber negativos. Mas também não ganha pontos com positivos.

Comment: Para entender porque recebeu voto negativo em uma pergunta é bom você Ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas)