# Fiz uma pergunta mesmo com a conta inautorizada

Tags: suporte, bug, perguntas

Há alguns dias atrás, eu tentei fazer uma pergunta no SOpt, e o site me deixou fazer a pergunta sem nenhum problema. Mas minha conta já estava há muito tempo sem permissão de realizar mais perguntas. Após fazer e postar essa pergunta, o SOpt voltou ao normal, não me permitindo de realizar mais perguntas.

O algoritmo me liberou a uma pergunta? Como e por que eu pude realizar uma pergunta sendo que minha conta não estava autorizada a realizá-la?

A pergunta que fiz e o SOpt autorizou [foi essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/464815/cadastro-de-dados-em-um-array-din%C3%A2mico-retornando-eaccesviolation).

Comment: Isso é devido ao veto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans, assim que suas postagens, como respostas forem boas e ultrapassarem as perguntas ruins ou deletadas você sairá do veto, você deve ter muitas perguntas deletadas com problemas, o algoritimo indica que isso é uma atuação ruim no site, o que vocÊ pode tentar fazer é restaurar as perguntas ruins que você pode melhorar, se for realmente possivel melhorar algumas delas e isso já ajudaria.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi. Mas as perguntas que eu realizei e apaguei, como posso explicar, foi apagada pois realmente ela não era necessária no SOpt. Eu apaguei justamente porque foi uma pergunta ruim. E alterar a mesma não iria tirar o fato que continuaria sendo uma pergunta ruim

Comment: E é assim que o algoritimo reconhece que vocÊ esta tendo uma atuação ruim, não é boa, você esta aqui provavelmente mais buscando o helpdesk, o algoritimo não é muito inteligente, ele deixa passar muito helpdesk e até postangens não tão bem feitas, não é que o algoritimo exija perfeição, porque de fato ele não exige, tem muita coisa que passa, mas suas atitudes de trazer conteudo e participar não são produtivas, você pode até não entender e não concordar, mas tem que ter em mente que sempre podemos melhorar nossa atuação em sites e grupos abertos.

Comment: Inicialmente eu estava procurando por helpdesk, mas depois de um tempo, entendi que não se trata somente só da linguagem, mas a lógica tem uma parte muito importante nisso, que eu valorizo muito, tanto é que tento fazer perguntas mais relacionadas a lógica com aquela linguagem do que com código em si, pois isso ajuda muito no conhecimento (principalmente pra mim que sou muito iniciante). Eu entendo o porquê do algoritmo ter me tirado a permissão de perguntar, e eu já estava tranquilo com o fato de não fazer perguntas, só não tinha entendido o motivo de ter sido permitido a perguntar novamente.

Comment: Você deve ter feito alguma boa contribuição sem perceber, talvez respondeu a algo, ganhou score.

Comment: Eu estava fazendo algumas participações no SO, que tiveram respostas positivas e um número significativo de visualizações, poderia ser isso?

Comment: Se você acha que o provável motivo de seu bloqueio foi a baixa qualidade das suas perguntas, aconselho ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas) e, dentro do possível, procurar melhorar suas publicações.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com o [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/401803):

> "*If you're blocked from asking and unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question*"

Em tradução livre:

> "Se você está bloqueado para perguntas e não conseguiu melhorar as já existentes, terá a chance de fazer uma nova pergunta 6 meses depois da última feita."

Vendo [seu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/124573/riki481?tab=questions), sua [última pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/387998/112052) (antes [da que foi mencionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/464815/cadastro-de-dados-em-um-array-din%C3%A2mico-retornando-eaccesviolation)) tinha sido há mais de 1 ano atrás (a menos que haja alguma outra que foi apagada nesse meio tempo, mas não sei se perguntas apagadas entram nessa contagem dos 6 meses).

Enfim, se você ainda está bloqueado para perguntas, então provavelmente foi isso.

Comment: Faz sentido, obrigado pela explicação. Se nessas perguntas semestrais eu conseguisse ter mais perguntas boas do que as ruins que já fiz, o algoritmo iria me desbloquear, ou o bloqueio continuaria?

Comment: @riki481 Aí eu já não sei, se não me engano o algoritmo não é público (para evitar que as pessoas tentem burlá-lo) e não dá pra ter certeza se o critério é só esse. O mesmo FAQ que mencionei diz para tentar melhorar as perguntas existentes, entre outras instruções (eu recomendo que leia tudo que tem lá, é a melhor fonte sobre o assunto, qualquer coisa que eu afirmar aqui será especulação)