# É necessário ter um conhecimento básico ou intermediário em linguagens de programação?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, comportamento

Gostaria de saber, em que *nível de conhecimento* sobre uma *linguagem de programação* o usuário deve estar para realizar perguntas? Sabendo o fundamental, como tipos de variáveis, operadores condicionais e lógicos, listas, estruturas condicionais e  de repetição já pode se considerar uma base suficiente ou é recomendado que o usuário esteja em uma fase mais prática como a construção de um projeto?

Comment: Tanto faz o nível de conhecimento, **desde que a pergunta esteja dentro do escopo**. E sobre "escopo" e como fazer uma boa pergunta, já tem bastante informação [aqui](/q/8388/112052), [aqui](/q/8496/112052), [aqui](/q/5483/112052), [aqui](/q/8045/112052) e [aqui](/q/7256/112052)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco confusa se quer saber isso de forma geral ou se quer saber se o site exige um mínimo de conhecimento para fazer perguntas.

Se for o primeiro a pergunta deveria ser fechada porque o meta é para discutir o site e não programação.

Se for o segundo, o site exige um mínimo de conhecimentos para fazer uma pergunta. A pergunta deve ser feita de forma clara, completa, simples, sem ser repetitiva, não pedir materiais ou opiniões, ou que exija uma resposta muito grande, ou ainda que o autor só quer que [alguém faça o trabalho dele](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/100416). As pessoas falham muito nisso porque elas não possuem conhecimentos suficientes de comunicação e expressão, então não conseguem fazer uma pergunta simples e objetiva de forma clara.

E muitas vezes as pessoas se complicam por falta de capacidade de interpretação de texto ou por não ler tudo o que é disponibilizado para a pessoa se dar bem no site. Então ela não pode ter preguiça de ler a documentação e deve entender esses textos, bem como os comentários que os usuários passam para elas, o que frequentemente elas acabam falhando também.

Além disso não entendem que [algumas perguntas já foram feitas e ela não precisa fazer de novo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), ou que ela quer delegar o trabalho dela, ou seja, é requisito que a pessoa se esforce antes de perguntar.

Também tem que ter uma uma noção razoável de matemática (nada muito avançado, é o básico mesmo). Sem isso, não dá para discutir programação com a pessoa. Muita gente falha nisso.

Note que não estou falando ainda de conhecimentos programação.

Outro problema é a pessoa fazer coisas mais complexas do que ela é capaz.
Se ela sabe nada de programação deve começar por um código bem simples, deve aprender os conceitos, sem fazer suposições. Deve estudar aquele assunto bem específico.

Um erro comum é a pessoa colocar coisas complexas que ela não tem ideia do que se trata, ela copiou, colou, mudou alguma coisa e deu um erro que ela nem saber ler. Fica difícil ajudar uma pessoa assim. A metodologia toda está errada. E geralmente a pessoa que faz isso é teimosa e não muda o seu jeito mesmo depois de alertado por pessoas experientes que isso não funciona.

Quando ela está fazendo algo mais complexo do que ela se preparou, ela não tem o alicerce para aquilo. É comum ela não conseguir fazer a pergunta direito, ela não tem como. Sem base alguma, tudo vira chute.

Se ela for passo por passo, devagar, se ela está preparada no básico, mesmo que a pergunta seja sobre um Hello World (que já tivemos aqui), fica bem mais fácil. A pessoas precisa ter paciência.

E a pessoa precisa lembrar que ela precisa de ajuda, e as pessoas que estão aqui estão fazendo isso de graça. Muitos são pessoas com muita experiência e não precisam ajudar ninguém. É obrigação de quem pergunta fazer uma pergunta atrativa para essas pessoas se interessarem por ela. Não é um serviço pago (ainda que os donos já ganharam dezenas de dólares por resposta postada aqui). Não é um serviço social.

Todos os níveis de programadores podem fazer perguntas boas. Nenhum nível de programador pode fazer perguntas ruins.

Só posso lamentar quando a pessoa tem falhas básicas, anteriores à programação, e não consegue fazer uma pergunta boa.

E especificamente, mandar um enunciado para as pessoas fazerem o código para você não é uma boa pergunta, não tem um problema no que está fazendo. Fazer a pergunta de novo depois dela ter sido fechada é um abuso em qualquer site bem administrado.

Olhar as [perguntas com boa votação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) dá um ideia do que é aceitável.

Comment: Irei realizar mais pesquisas no site para observar os padrões de perguntas e aprender mais sobre a plataforma, uma vez que pelo que pude entender a pergunta deve ser objetiva.

Comment: Resumindo, não é obrigatório, mas, sem um conhecimento mínimo, é improvável que seja feita uma pergunta minimamente descente (clara e objetiva)

Comment: *"E muitas vezes as pessoas se complicam por falta de capacidade de interpretação de texto ou por não ler tudo o que é disponibilizado para a pessoa se dar bem no site"* fora esse ponto, também vejo que as pessoas tem dificuldade de se expressar, não fazem uma simples validação do tipo "se alguém ler a minha pergunta, será que vai entender claramente qual é a minha duvida?", ou ainda pedir pra um colega ler e ver se ele consegue entender (claro sem estar a par de todo o contexto), em resumo, as pessoas tem dificuldade de redigir uma boa pergunta (comunicação e expressão)