# Aumentar o tempo de marcação de "Aceitar resposta"

Tags: debate

Se não me engano, hoje são **10 minutos**, ou menos, para **aceitar uma resposta**.

Isso em certa parte, **dá uma "limitada/esfriada"** em quem quer fazer uma **resposta mais completa**, melhor elaborada/exemplificada/detalhada, porque o cara resolve o problema dele, marca a resposta, e nem volta mais. O outro que chega ao tópico por onde quer que seja, acaba indo na marcada como aceita.

Pensando no fluxo básico e mais curto, **30 minutos** seria o ideal:

1. Pergunta
2. Respostas
3. Testes
4. Homologação

Mesmo que uma resposta simples resolveu o problema, **uma resposta mais elaborada**, explicando "os porquês" de cada linha/detalhe, seria a **"mais correta"**.

Fica a sugestão.

Comment: Acho que sou o cara que mais toma -1 nesse meta! hahaha

Comment: Quem decide se a resposta está correta ou não é o autor da pergunta. Apesar de alguns escolherem a resposta q nem sempre é a mais completa, isso é um direito de cada um que pergunta. E a pergunta nao fica trancada depois que uma resposta é aceita, o pessoal tem que parar de achar que nao pode responder so porque o autor ja aceitou uma resposta. Se tem uma resposta mais completa, vai la e poste, voce estará colaborando ainda mais. pra qualidade daquela pergunta.

Comment: Então, mas porque não dar uma "forçada" no cara fazer uma boa resposta e não só ficar correndo por pontos!? Seria uma simples "trava" nisso. Acho que isso daria mais "qualidade" na pesquisa.

Comment: É muita gente que vem aqui só pra resolver o problema e nem entende o porque/como/onde. Além dos que nem marcam uma resposta e só voltam depois de um tempo para "resolver um problema" e sumir outra vez...

Comment: Ao meu ver, completamente desnecessário. Você já tem o negativo pra isso, resposta ruim e mal elaborada? Negativo nela. Pra que punir ainda mais? Acho que deveriamos focar no que é mais importante, que é melhorar a qualidade com boas respostas, e atenuar as ruins com votos negativos, porque uma hora o cara vai ver aquela enchurrada de -x e vai se tocar que tem algo errado, isso ja é punicao suficiente. Se acha que a resposta está incompleta, complemente com a sua. Já vi casos de respostas inundadas de upvote enquanto a aceita quase nao recebeu nada é o peso da comunidade fazendo valer.

Comment: Mas eu não posso dar -1 em uma resposta que resolveu o problema do cara! Eu só dou -1 quando está errada ou realmente não dá para entender. Mas eu entendi o que você disse. Você prefere deixar da forma que está, mais livre, e a minha sugestão ela "diminuiria" de certa forma esses casos, fazendo o cara elaborar melhor.

Comment: @RBZ: *"Acho que sou o cara que mais toma -1 nesse meta! hahaha"* nossa.. :)

Comment: Diminuiria de forma alguma, quem quer responder, vai responder, seja resposta ruim ou nao. O que voce vai conseguir com esse tipo de limitacao é reduzir o numero de respostas do site, afinal, se o cara vem aqui com um tempinho q tem e ve uma pergunta pra responder e tem que esperar, ele vai desistir. Isso so desestimularia as pessoas sem reputacao alta a participar. Eu prefiro que se tenha muitas respostas sem limitacoes, mesmo com algumas ruins, o voto e sinalização é justamente para estes casos, nao podemos punir todos pelo que alguns fazem.

Comment: É, agora você me convenceu... "Isso so desestimularia as pessoas sem reputacao alta a participar. Eu prefiro que se tenha muitas respostas sem limitacoes, mesmo com algumas ruins, o voto e sinalização é justamente para estes casos, nao podemos punir todos pelo que alguns fazem." Mas de certa forma, estaria "errado" -1 em uma resposta correta mas fraca

Comment: @RBZ só um esclarecimento meio off, o negativo aqui é diferente do site pincipal, ele tem como significado de que a pessoa discorda de você, apenas isso, nao afeta sua reputacao e nao indica baixa qualidade, apenas discordancia, nao esquenta com negativos aqui nao ;)

Comment: Uma coisa que eu aprendi não tem muito como forçar ninguém fazer nada, especialmente aqui, mesmo incentivar costuma dar errado, como vemos todos os dias. Claro, não fazer nada também dá errado. E é raro surgir uma ideia que realmente resolva essas questões humanas, embora estamos sempre esperando que suja algo. A questão dos sanguessugas não tenho solução, você tem? Sua "solução" não diminuiria nada, seria inócua, a não ser que eu não tenha entendido, esclareça. Bom, diminuiria a quantidade de aceitações. Dá pra questionar até os 10min.

Comment: A solução é notificar e-mail do cara, exigir uma ação antes de fazer a próxima, mesmo que seja "quero aceitar depois", ou alguma coisa assim, precisaria elaborar uma proposta. Eu acho que precisa classificar mais e punir menos, ter melhores ferramentas pra deixar mais claro de forma simples, sem peso pro avaliador, que algo é ruim, sem facilitar pro abuso, o que é difícil, mas dá pra fazer alguma coisa, dá pra testar.

Comment: @Articuno a sim cara, super de boa! ;)

Comment: Havia colocado uma resposta, mas ficou "fora" do que é perguntado conforme apontou o @Articuno, por isso removi. Tinha sugerido um sistema de "lembrar" o usuário que fez a pergunta de votar numa resposta depois de um tempo, mas tem uma pergunta aqui já relacionada a isso: [Pergunta já tem resposta definida, porém não foi marcada como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/452/57220)

Comment: @Maniero você entendeu certo. Mas como o Articuno disse, realmente iriam aumentar respostas sem aceite. E como você disse, ter algo que faça o cara voltar e confirmar uma resposta, aí sim, na minha opinião, aumentar o tempo iria melhorar a qualidade e diminuir downvote, mas voltaríamos novamente no comentário do Articuno, nós (eu e outros) com baixa reputação, seríamos desestimulados, porque quer queira ou não, há um "favoritismo" com os melhores pontuados, seja por bobeira, medo do cara não gostar, etc. Enfim, como você disse "não tem muito como forçar ninguém fazer nada", realmente é verdade

Comment: @RicardoPontual acho que essa questão será meio eterna! rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns fatos para vc refletir e levar em consideração...

**Fato 1:** *O Autor da pergunta pode mudar a qualquer momento a resposta aceita.* Então se ele aceitou a primeira resposta que apareceu e depois surgiu outra mais interessante o Autor da Pergunta pode facilmente mudar a resposta aceita.

**Fato 2:** Repostas não aceitas com votação maior que a aceita é algo muito comum, não nas proporções que se vê na *Medalha Populista*, mas é algo tão comum que até existe uma medalha para isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist

**Fato 3:** Se todos pensassem como vc não teríamos Perguntas aqui com mais de 20 respostas. A Pergunta já ter uma resposta aceita não é motivo para vc não colaborar visto que o STOF é uma plataforma colaborativa de base no acumulo de conhecimento.

**Fato 4:** Muitas vezes um problema pode ser resolvido com mais de uma maneira, se já responderam como fazer do jeito A e foi aceito, colabore demonstrando como fazer do jeito B, afinal no futuro essa Pergunta mais completa vai ajudar a comunidade.

E por ai vai. Não vejo nada de errado com o sistema atual.

Comment: O fato 1 é verdade, mas esse pode é bem frágil. o fato 2 me parece interpretação errada, a medalha, inclusive de ouro, é porque é raro. O fato 3 também está esquisito, era isso mesmo? Quer rever se era esse texto?

Comment: F1 - Sim/Não porque tem mais gente dos tipos: que só quer resolver o problema, que não liga para ir mais a fundo, que as vezes não questiona 100% da dúvida, que não volta numa pergunta resolvida (seja por tempo, etc), entre outros.
F2 - Não conhecia essa medalha, mas parece que tem poucos.
F3 - Em casos 1 resposta bem feita seria melhor que 30 respostas. Claro que cada caso é um caso, e sempre aprendemos com a diversidade.
F4 - Idem ao F3. Mas é isso aí... já mudei partes do conceito da minha susgestão! rs

Comment: @Maniero deu uma ajustada no Fato 3, a intenção era dizer que uma Resposta já aceita na pergunta não é um motivo para deixar de contribuir caso vc tenha algo a acrescentar. No Fato 2 como falei a proporção do badge é difícil mesmo, mas resposta não aceita com pontuação maior que a aceita é algo comum